# Get NN.NNNNN format in decimal.ToString() in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How i can get format NN.NNNN,NN after decimal.ToString()

I tried:

```
value.ToString("00.0000,00")
```

But on output i have in NN.NNNNNN format, without comma...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear to me what you try to achieve, but one thing that is clear is that you swapped placed with the thousand separator and the comma separator. It should be:

```
value.ToString("00,0000.00")
```

In the format string, the comma character (',') is a placeholder for the comma separator character, it does not represent a literal comma. Same for the period character ('.'): it's a placeholder for the number group separator. These will be replaced with the actual comma and number group separators from the format provider used (the current culture if none is passed to the `ToString` method).

Still it may be that the output is not what you want. I get the following output for

```
instance:
double value = 123456.7890123;

// prints "123 456,79"
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00,0000.00"));
```

If you want other groupings, you will need to supply a suitable [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) object:

```
double value = 123456.7890123;
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo
    {
        NumberDecimalDigits = 2,
        NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
        NumberGroupSeparator = ",",
        NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 4, 2 }
    };
// prints "12,3456.79"
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00,0000.00", nfi));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
value.ToString("00.0000\\,00");
```

Comment: Using an en-US culture, this will output 12345.6789 as `12345.6789,00`. Pretty confusing in my book.

Comment: @FredrikMörk Completely agree with you. But if that is what he wants to do then this is how you do it. I didn't say that I agree with such a format ;).